# OAuth2 mechanism in Google Account

Tags: python, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, python-3.10

I have set a Project in the Google API Console, getting my `client_id` and `client_secret`. This App is a mail app that accesses to my Gmail Account.

I also managed to get a `refresh_token` and an `access_token` through the OAuth2 Playground of Google Developers.

Then I used immediately the access token to get a authentication string, and then used the latter for accessing my Gmail account successfully. But the `access_token` expires in 1 h.

The problem is that I can't refresh my `access_token` with the permanent `refresh_token`.

I am using `oauth2.py` from `OAuth2DotPy`: `https://github.com/google/gmail-oauth2-tools/wiki/OAuth2DotPyRunThrough`, and run this code line:

```
python3 oauth2.py --user=xxx@gmail.com \
 --client_id=111.apps.googleusercontent.com \
 --client_secret=XXX \
 --refresh_token=1//1/1/1//1
```

The error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/.../oauth2.py", line 353, in <module>
    main(sys.argv)
  File "/home/.../oauth2.py", line 312, in main
    response = RefreshToken(options.client_id, options.client_secret,
  File "/home/.../oauth2.py", line 247, in RefreshToken
    response = urllib.request.urlopen(request_url, urllib.parse.urlencode(params).encode('utf-8')).read()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/urllib/request.py", line 216, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/urllib/request.py", line 525, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/urllib/request.py", line 634, in http_response
    response = self.parent.error(
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/urllib/request.py", line 563, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/urllib/request.py", line 496, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/urllib/request.py", line 643, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 401: Unauthorized
```

Does any one have a clue?

*** EDIT: ***

I also tried to use the `python` `oauth2.py` to generate my tokens, using my client id and secret, like this:

```
python3 oauth2.py --generate_oauth2_token --user=xxx@gmail.com \
 --client_id=11111.apps.googleusercontent.com \
 --client_secret=XXXXXXXX
```

which replied with:

```
To authorize token, visit this url and follow the directions:
  https://accounts.google.com/...%2F
Enter verification code: _
```

I followed the URL and Google answers me with a screen saying "Blocked Access : The request of this app is invalid" and "Error 400: redirect_uri_mismatch"

** EDIT **

I have allowed the app OAuth2 (url: https://oauth2.dance) in my Google Console, and all worked ok.

With

```
python3 oauth2.py --generate_oauth2_token --user=xxx@gmail.com \
 --client_id=XXX.... \
 --client_secret=XXX
```

I was able to get a code that entered in the `oauth2.py` program gave me the permanent refresh token.

Comment: Why are you using playground

Comment: OAuth2 Playground is a tool from Google, that gives me a refresh token and an access token (this valid for 3600 seconds). This access token is good for accessing my Gmail via IMAP, but it only lasts 1h. Do you have another method?
I need to refresh the access tokens each time I access my account (daily)...

Comment: Playground is used for testing only it not a production ready solution.   Request access with python and let it handle everything